# How do I get a <div> to always be in the top right corner of the browser window regardless of browser size?

Tags: html, css

I want the following code to always be in top right, regardless of the size (i.e. when the user resizes the browser window, it is still in the same position):

```
<div id="navbar"><a href="#">Our Blog</a></div>
```

The CSS that accompanies this as follows:

```
#navbar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 850px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;    
}
```

I would like to do it in CSS and HTML only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change it from being positioned form the left to be positioned from the right...

```
#navbar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  padding:  15px 0 0 0;
}
```